# Iterate through an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

Hi I have a simple question: how do I iterate through an array. The array below contains strings to be modified through a regex command.

```
foreach(@array)
{
    $count = 0;
    @array[$count] =~ /regex here../;
    $count++;
}
```

I am able to modify the first object in the array but not the rest. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You are already iterating through the array with the `foreach(@array)` construct. At every iteration of the loop, `$_` is set to the respective element of the array.

Comment: Thanks I wasnt aware of the $_ syntax, new to perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply :

```
foreach(@array)
{
    /regex here../;
}
```

or

```
foreach my $a (@array)
{
    $a =~ /regex here../;
}
```

or

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $#array) 
{
    $array[$i] =~ /regex here.../;
}
```